# shell: extract string from source code

Tags: shell

Is there a simple way to extract strings from code i.e. the content of a double quotes?

source:

```
a = "somestring"
```

result:

```
somestring
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple first attempt:

```
egrep -o '"([^"]*)"' sourcefile | sed -r 's/"(.*)"/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Fred Foo's answer solves the essential problem. Expanding to report across a directory tree, and to report the file name on each output line even if multiple strings occur on the same line:

```
find . -name '*.java' | xargs egrep -o '"([^"]*)"' |\
awk '/:"/ {j=$0;sub(/:.*/,"",j);print;}!/:"/{print j ":" $0}' |\
sed 's/"\(.*\)"/\1/'
```