# Isolate Strings from Java sourcecode

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, parsing

Is there an elegant way to parse Java sourcecode and to isolate its Strings?

I would like to do that to copy all Strings into an office file with which I can run German spell-checking.

Comment: Do you want to do that with Java? I would use Perl to read the .java files and search for regexes in the file

Comment: Have you tried to remove the check on "Ignore Java String literals" in the Eclipse settings for the spell checker and adding a german user dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You could use properties files

http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/java-basic/974-how-use-properties-file-java.html

Comment: if German is the only supported language, then it seems overkill to add property files only for spell checking.

Comment: Leaves you with the nice side effects of being able to internationalise very easily and reuse text though.

Comment: Copy and paste the properties file into MsOffice. Or Write a small application before, that just extracts the values. Everything after "=" in each line.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a heap dump of your application via jvisualvm, it will save all present in memory String instances. The result will be stored in .hprof file, see [How do I analyze a .hprof file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185893/how-do-i-analyze-a-hprof-file)

Comment: Tricky, but what if not all strings are loaded? And German and English strings (English from the JDK classes) would be mixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, like in this question: [shell: extract string from source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626516/shell-extract-string-from-source-code)

But probably the better way would be to configure the spell checker of your IDE.